# Which info does the NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS provide?

Tags: java, android, 3g, telephonymanager

I am using 
`TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS`  to find if my `Sim` is 3G enabled

But not sure if `TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS` provides the `Device` Capability information or the `SIM` is 3G enabled!

Can anyone give me more Info? or is it possible to check `SIM` UMTS/3G Info/Capabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, assuming the documentation and type naming is accurate and that it behaves the same way in all devices, this is telling you the type of the network you are connected to, not the device type nor the SIM type.

You might for example have a 3G capable SIM (or 4G now...) but be in a network coverage area which only supports GPRS or EDGE etc.

The TelephonyManager flag simply tells you what your current network connectivity is.